# Rollback own edit before 2k rep

Tags: feature-request, rollbacks

Would it makes sense to allow for rollback of your own edits without having to have 2000 reputation? What if your submitted edit had a mistake but got approved anyway?

What about recalling an edit before it's been reviewed?

Comment: It would sound like the reviewers would need to have a "conversation" with someone about that.

Comment: What if other edits have been applied subsequently? Are we going to allow novices to roll them back too? If not it's kind of niche, if so it's too powerful.

Comment: I see. I was only thinking about the case where more edits haven't been made yet. What about recalling an edit before it's been reviewed?